# Node.js JSON undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```
{ _id: 55cacecf5bccb3b660b4e0af,
  created_at: Wed Aug 12 2015 12:42:55 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  updated_at: Wed Aug 12 2015 12:42:55 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  id: '0000',
  keyname: 'Test Key 3',
  postalcode: '652811',
  starttime: Fri Jul 31 2015 11:33:22 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  endtime: Fri Jul 31 2015 11:33:22 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  __v: 0 }
```

When i tried to get the id using, `json.id` it gives me an undefined.

I tried parsing as JSON using `JSON.parse` and it gives me this error. This JSON is from MongoDB

`undefined:1
{ _id: 55cacecf5bccb3b660b4e0af,
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _`

Comment: That is not JSON. JSON is always a string, and needs quotes around keys, and also around string values like `55cacecf5bccb3b660b4e0af` and `Wed Aug 12 2015 12:42:55 GMT+0800 (SGT)`. Also, you don't have an attribute called `id`, you have one called `_id`.

Comment: Is there any method i can convert this into JSON? My attribute `id` is 0000

Comment: It is very unclear what "this" is. Is it an object, that you printed out and copied what came out? Then "maybe" - JSON does not support dates, so they should be rendered as string or as timestamp. Is it a string that you somehow have? Then it would be a lot of work, and you should try to get the underlying object instead.

Comment: You are clearly using mongoose ( not mentioned in the tags ) to return an Object from MongoDB. It is not "JSON" but just a plain JavaScript object, or more specifically a "mongoose document". As something returned from mongoose there should be an "id" accessor that is already present as an alias to the `_id` field that is mandatory unless you explicity called `.toObject()` to return a plain object or used "raw". So you just access properties like any other JavaScript object. MongoDB does not speak JSON but BSON, and that is always marshalled by the driver into a native language form.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mongoose query result. So don't parse it using JSON, just use `_id` to get the value.

Ex:

if the query result is `data`, use `data._id` to access the `_id` field.